# Creating namedtuple instance from already set values

Tags: python, namedtuple

I have a `namedtuple` like this

```
course_summary_struct = namedtuple(
                'CourseSummary',
                ['id', 'display_name', 'location', 'display_coursenum', 'display_organization']
)
```

I want to update the the `namedtuple` dynamically until I am sure it has all required information.

So i Update `course_summary_struct` with all the values in steps.

Now I am at a place where I need to create an instance from `course_summary_struct` like this

```
summery = course_summary_struct() #<===== Issue here
```

I want to fill `summery` with all the information in `course_summary_struct`.

How can I do that?

Comment: `tuples` are immutable, is there a reason you are using them?...why not `dict` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wait until you have all the necessary information before actually creating the named tuple instance.

```
data = {}
data['id'] = 3
# ...
data['display_name'] = 'Chem 101'
# ...
summary = course_summary_struct._make([data[x] for x in course_summary_struct._fields])
```

Answer (score 1):

Tuples are immutable and can not be changed after their creation.

You can use [`recordclass.recordclass`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/recordclass).

Answer (score 0):

If you have data in Dictionary you can do this way

```
course_summary_struct = namedtuple(
                'CourseSummary',
                ['id', 'display_name', 'location', 'display_coursenum', 'display_organization'])
# Your data
data = {
    'id': 1,
    'display_name': 'naren',
    'location': 'Bengaluru',
    'display_coursenum': 11,
    'display_organization': ':D'}

course_summary_struct(**data)

# Creates > CourseSummary(id=1, display_name='naren', location='Bengaluru', display_coursenum=11, display_organization=':D')
```

Or if you have other way use `setattr`

```
setattr(course_summary_struct, 'id', 11)
```